# Gulp run watch task once at start

Tags: node.js, gulp

When starting to watch my files, the file system might have changed, when the watch was not on-line. How can I make my watch run the task once at start, after typing in the command `gulp dev`?

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*', ['scss','inject']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('dev', ['scss', 'inject', 'watch']);
```

This way those tasks run first, and then the watch task starts so any changes to the files are accounted for prior to the Watch task starting.

Comment: Oh, and then I rename the `'dev'`-task above to `'watch'`?

Comment: No. What the above code does is create a new task named 'dev' that is a chain of tasks they you have defined. So when you type 'gulp dev', gulp will first run the 'scss' task, then the 'inject' task, and finally the 'watch' task.

Comment: But I have no task named `watch`, so I need to rename my task above and create a new task called `dev` as you specified above...right? I did this and it works :)

Comment: Sorry, misread what you write. Yes, you were correct.Glad it works :)

Comment: if it doesn't work use: `gulp.task('dev', gulp.series(['scss', 'inject', 'watch']));`

Answer (score 3):

This is all built into gulp-watch, no need to hard code a new task!

Gulp watch includes an option called `ignoreInitial` which is `true` by default. To run the task once at start simply set this to `false`:

```
gulp.task('dev', { ignoreInitial: false }, function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*', ['scss','inject']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To run the `default` task before `watch`:

```
gulp.task('watch', [ 'default' ], function () {
    gulp.watch('themes/my-theme/scss/**/*.scss', ['build-scss']);
    gulp.watch('images/*', ['compress-images']);
});
```